# Image recognition and sort of automatic calibration

Tags: java

I am not sure how to describe my questions headline to point out my question in one sentence (english is not my native language so please do not flame me for it)

I have the following szenario.
An image is displayed on a computer display. a camera (webcam or similar) is pointed towards the disolay so the image observed will cover nearly the whole video frame, but might be a bit disorted.

How can i calibrate/detect the bounds of the image?
For calibration purposes i could display a test picture. The camera and displayed image will NOT change its position after calibration!

My only idea would be to click some reference points with my mouse. Automatic detection like in QR code would be preferred/perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calibration points similarly to QR code. Place three black squires in the calibration image corners. As the result you'll obtain an area (inside a rectangle, set by calibration points) that can be used as a boundary for all further images.

Comment: actually this is what i wrote in my question, but your answer does not provide any help in how to do so